# Redux dispatching an action that contains a method to be called from reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I started playing with redux and thought to myself that creating reducer functions with long `if` or `switch` statement seems unorganized and ugly. So I created a proof of concept when the state mutation logic would live with in the action creator, but I am not sure if I am violating some Flux or redux principle by doing it this way. I was wondering if there is any major drawbacks to putting this logic into the action object that is dispatched.

## Proof of Concept Example

Create store with reducer that executes mutation method from dispatched action:

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
const store = createStore((state, action) => {
    if (action.mutation) {
        const mutatedStated = action.mutation({ ...state });
        return { ...state, ...mutatedStated };
    }
    return state;
});
```

Then action creators with method to generate a new state object:

```
export const updateName = (name) => {
    return {
        mutation(state) {
            return { ...state, name };
        },
        type: "UPDATE_NAME",
    }
}
```

usage:

```
store.dispatch(updateName("Your friend Ken"))
```

```js
const createStore = Redux.createStore;
const store = createStore((state, action) => {
  if (action.mutation) {
    const mutatedStated = action.mutation({ ...state
    });
    return { ...state,
      ...mutatedStated
    };
  }
  return state;
});

// inital state
store.dispatch({
  type: "testing",
  mutation: () => {
    return {
      name: "test"
    }
  }
});

console.log(store.getState());

// action creator
const setName = (name) => {
  return {
    mutation: (state) => {
      return { ...state,
        name
      }
    },
    type: "set name"
  }
}

store.dispatch(setName("Your friend Ken!"));

console.log(store.getState());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.1/redux.js"></script>
```

Comment: One disadvantage with this approach is the tendency for excessive `state` cloning. Here the state is cloned/spread/merged ~ 3 times. This can get quite expensive as the app scales.

Comment: Yeah, that can be cleaned up, but it is just a POC.

Comment: @YourFriendKen please see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

State update logic should be independent of actions so that different reducers can update state in different ways given the same action. Including state-updating logic in an action couples the two, and if multiple reducers needed to handle the action, you would have to write a state-update callback in the action for each different reducer.

If you want to keep your reducers clean, just factor out the complicated stuff into utility functions.